# How to set a cursor image via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Inside a web application I have a loading event. If the browser is loading data from the server, I want the cursor change to a gif that shows a clock. How can I change the cursor appearance. I only found this in the blog referring cursor apperance:

```
$(this).css('cursor','move');
```

I want to load an image instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(this).css( 'cursor', 'url(cursor.png), auto' );
```

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fv3Bk/1/
The `auto` parameter tells what cursor type to use if cursor' image is not found. (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/cursor.html) more cursor types, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fv3Bk/4/) the example with another one )

Comment: what does auto stand for? I wanted to create a class, but where to put 'auto' then

Comment: In IE a .cur file is required

Answer (score 9):

If you want the cursor to be a cursor of your choice you can use the css cursor property like above, but with the url value:

```
$(this).css('cursor', 'url(/path/to/image),auto');
```

or to all inside the body:

```
$('body').css('cursor', 'url(/path/to/image),auto');
```

As far as I know this won't work in Opera.