# changing cursor url depending on background-position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my code is like this :

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Pencil_a" class="Pencil"></a>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Pencil_a").click(function () {
            $("body").addClass("pencil_cursor");
        });
    });
</script>
```

style:

```
.Pencil
{
    background-image: url("images/globaleImg.png");
    background-position: -88px -415px;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 15px;
}
.pencil_cursor
{
    cursor:url("images/globaleImg.png") -88px -415px;
    display:block;
}
```

when I click on the link the cursor don't change it's default image what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your `Container_div` class tag?

Comment: it's not Container_div it's the body tag i edited my question

Comment: Have you defined an other custom cursor somewhere else ? If so, you must check that the new one is overriding the previous one. Try to use `cursor:url(...) !important;`

Comment: @Sora: check my answer, this is due image size restrictions

Comment: @TomSarduy It's not necessarily down to the size of the image - we don't even know how big the image is!  The issue is the `px` in the cursor CSS (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem #1

> The coordinates of the cursor's hotspot, which will be clamped to the
>   boundaries of the cursor image. If none are specified, the coordinates
>   of the hotspot are read from the file itself (for CUR and XBM files)
>   or are set to the top left corner of the image.

An example of the CSS3 syntax is:

```
.foo  {
    cursor:  auto;
    //no pixel value, or negative
    cursor:  url(cursor1.png) 4 12, auto;
}
```

#### Problem #2

From [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcursor%2Furl#Limitations)

> In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger
>   cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the
>   size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and
>   platforms.
>
> (Due to a bug in Gecko 1.9.2-1.9.2.6, Firefox 3.6-3.6.6 on Windows
>   limits to 32x32px. This is fixed in later versions.)

#### Fiddle:

Check this fiddle and you will see that is working, you just need an smaller image:

http://jsfiddle.net/F4uU5/1/

Comment: It's not necessarily down to the size of the image - we don't even know how big the image is!  The issue is the `px` in the cursor CSS (see my answer)

Comment: @olimortimer: yes, that's an issue but, even without the pixels, it wont work... I don't know exactly the image size, but the OP is using `background-position: -88px -415px;`, so, it's bigger than 88x415 ;)

Comment: You can position a 1x1 image with -88px -415px.  It doesn't mean the image is bigger than 88x415

Comment: @olimorter: yes, but that don't make any sense, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `cursor:url("images/globaleImg.png"),auto;`

```
.pencil_cursor
{
    cursor:url("images/globaleImg.png"),auto;
    display:block;
}
```

[see stackoverflow ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389957/how-to-set-a-cursor-image-via-jquery)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8X7N/)

Comment: Your fiddle is applying the new cursor to a particular div. Think the op wants to apply to whole page.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQejL/2/) try with this fiddle it works perfectly. just add jquery plugin because I couldn't update my fiddle.

Comment: The auto is a fallback, so not required

Comment: @Yashhy: I didn't downvoted your answer, not sure why you downvoted mine... but you should modify/delete this one!

Comment: @TomSarduy haha :D I need 128 Reputation to downvote [http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: @Yashhy: Oh, I see, your -2 rep is because the olimortimer downvote ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy yeah!! and `auto` callback **should be added** for your cursor property.

Comment: @Yashhy: +10, but next time explain why, people can think that you copy/paste ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is down to the `px` in the cursor CSS.  The `px` isn't required, just the numbers.

Change;

```
cursor:url("images/globaleImg.png") -88px -415px;
```

To;

```
cursor:url("images/globaleImg.png") -88 -415;
```

FYI, the X Y co-ords are to change the hotspot of the cursor, not the actual position of the image.

You should also add a fallback cursor, in case the browser can't load the custom one from the URL;

```
cursor:url("images/globaleImg.png") -88 -415, auto;
```

**Fixed**: http://jsfiddle.net/e8qVS/8/

---

As a side note, currently it thinks the body of the page is only as high as the href tag.  If you want to change the cursor for whole body of the page, you need to add the following to make sure the body is 100% of the height of the page;

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8qVS/3/

Comment: Yes, if you click the link and then hover off the link you will see the new cursor. Changing the cursor for body and a looks better but it's not flexible with other elements on the page. `$('body,a').css('cursor', 'progress');`

Comment: the problem is with the url

Comment: @TomSarduy the problem is with the X Y co-ords at the end of the cursor URL CSS

Comment: @olimortimer: How can you be so sure? ;) Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/

Comment: Ah fair enough @TomSarduy - it's the px on the co-ords which stops it from working.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: If you would read the link in the previous you would know that *"specifying the coordinates of the cursor's hotspot, which will be clamped to the boundaries of the cursor image"*. So, something like `-88 -415` won't work.

Comment: @olimortimer callback `auto` **should be added**. That's what I have answered already.